# Authentication in mongoose using SCRAM-SHA-1

Tags: mongoose

I recently upgraded from MongoDB 2.6 to 3.0.4 and also upgraded the Mongoose version to 4.0.0.

Now when ever i try to connect to mongo using mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname')
```

On mongo logs i receive this message

> SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for user on dbname from client
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I checked in mongodb, the user exists in the admin. The command that i used is
`db.system.users.findOne({user:'user'})`

The information returned by this statement contains SCRAM-SHA-1 information.

My question is how to specify SCRAM related information in mongoose while establishing connection. I read lots of articles, but failed to understand how its done

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the solution, I didn't passed the authDatabase name, that's why the connection failed. Earlier i was using this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname')
```

Now i used this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname?authSource=dbWithUserCredentials')
```

Found this solution on [Discussion thread](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1740) of Mongoose itself

**Edit:**

Don't forget to replace `dbWithUserCredentials` with your own. In most cases dbWithUserCredentials would be admin. All the credentials for login like username, password are already specified in the parameter passed to `mongoose.connect()`.

Comment: dbWithUserCredentials is just a string. Though its not a good name for a string. In most cases `dbWithUserCredentials` would be `admin`, but in my case `dbWithUserCredentials` was something else. All the credentials for login like `username`, `password` are already specified in the parameter passed to `mongoose.connect`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. It was fixed after updating mongoose to v4.1.11.

Comment: I'm running v4.4.10 but I still have this problem.  Specifying the auth source via @sunitj's answer worked for me.

Comment: Upgrading mongoose version helped me. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed to Mongoose version `4.0.3` and it works.