# Auth failed, code 18 when connecting to MongoLab database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to connect to a MongoLab database but keep getting the following error on connection:

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

The code I'm using to connect is:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@ds061474.mongolab.com:61474/apitest");

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I connect using the shell, I have no problems whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check if by accident you are using your mongolab.com username and password, instead of the database username and password?

Comment: Also, are you possibly using an old shell version to connect to mongodb newer version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have encountered similar problem when connecting the mongo db using mongoose. After exploring a while I found mongoLab is using SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication. 
Refer to the question below I tried to upgrade my mongoose to V4.1.11, and then it works for me

[Authentication in mongoose using SCRAM-SHA-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398367/authentication-in-mongoose-using-scram-sha-1)

Comment: upgrading mongoose version helped me..thanks :) 
refer this https://github.com/mongolab/hello-mongoose/commit/d873461a5cae8c914b4385f6259b2d7a83e164e3

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue while I try to import data from the locale to server.

Those 2 parameters can be important, it worked after I put them:

```
--authenticationMechanism 'MONGODB-CR' 
--authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Be careful about the auth mechanism, can be a different one. Check this part of documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-authenticationmechanism

Answer (score 1):

Had this error myself, turns out I did two things incorrectly (thanks Idos):

1. Used the mongolab.com username instead of the database one.
2. Tried to connect to a mongo 3.4 database using a 2.6 shell provided through Ubuntu's repositories. `mongo --version` to check.

Follow the instructions from [this MongoDB page](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to add their keys and repositories to your APT sources in order to upgrade and keep your MongoDB installation updated going forward.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar error in that case. put `authSourse=admin` and `ssl=true` to your connection

e.g

```
mongodb://username:password@ds061474.mongolab.com:61474/apitest?authSourse=admin&ssl=true
```

Comment: You have a typo, should be authSource not authSourse