# Could not connect to mongod from mongo shell when auth enabled (on ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

System: ubuntu 14.04

mongodb 3.0.3 tar ball is downloaded from mongodb download center

connected to mongodb without auth, then from mongo shell, created a user for 'test' db. following is the command.

```
db.createUser({user: "user1", 
               pwd: "test123", 
               roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" } 
 ]})
```

Verified that user details in admin db. Following is the command & result:

```
> db.system.users.findOne({user:'user1'})
{
    "_id" : "testdb.user1",
    "user" : "user1",
    "db" : "testdb",
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : 10000,
            "salt" : "kNfOd1vs+QT+ueH7SI6Vzw==",
            "storedKey" : "JCesIKSW1pb74ddo2Y19rEO1GVY=",
            "serverKey" : "d87Sb1htoD5K8zecAy73JPZyHdc="
        }
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now exit from the mongo shell, killed the mongod.
Started the mongodb with auth, following is the command.

```
$ ./mongod --auth
```

Connected to mongo shell as usual, see the below:

```
$ ./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
> show collections
2016-05-11T22:33:46.302+0530 E QUERY    Error: listCollections failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on test to execute command { listCollections: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DB._getCollectionInfosCommand (src/mongo/shell/db.js:646:15)
    at DB.getCollectionInfos (src/mongo/shell/db.js:658:20)
    at DB.getCollectionNames (src/mongo/shell/db.js:669:17)
    at shellHelper.show (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:625:12)
    at shellHelper (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:524:36)
    at (shellhelp2):1:1 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:646
> db.auth({user:'user1', pwd:'test123'})
1
> use test
switched to db test
> db.collone.insert({name:'firstcollection'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> show collections
collone
system.indexes
> db.collone.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5733669fb7d44cd444ebf028"), "name" : "firstcollection" }
> exit
bye
```

When i tried to do the authentication while starting the mongo shell, getting authentication failed error. See below:

```
$ ./mongo test -u 'user1' -p 'test123' --authenticationDatabase 'admin'
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
2016-05-11T22:37:21.559+0530 E QUERY    Error: 18 Authentication failed.
    at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1266:32)
    at (auth):6:8
    at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1266
exception: login failed
```

All this is just a POC that i'm trying to do.
Once it's success, my target is to connect from mongoose client(from Node.js app) to mongod.
The following command from a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398367/authentication-in-mongoose-using-scram-sha-1) post can help me to set up connection from mongoose to mongod with auth.

Comment: Still struggling with the same issue. Can someone offer some light?

Comment: Guys, anyone get a chance to review this?

Comment: Problem is solved, I was thinking that I should give 'admin' as authenticationDatabase but i was supposed to give 'test' where I've created user1.